# way to determine if app has been started by clicking on the notification

Tags: android, notifications

Is there a way to track determine if an android app has been started by clicking on the notification or by normal start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may put an [extra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) in the Intent that you use to create the PendingIntent for the     notification.

From the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ExtendedNotification):

```
// Instantiate a Builder object.
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
// Creates an Intent for the Activity
Intent notifyIntent =
        new Intent(new ComponentName(this, ResultActivity.class));
// Sets the Activity to start in a new, empty task
notifyIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
// Creates the PendingIntent
PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0,
        notifyIntent
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
);

// Puts the PendingIntent into the notification builder
builder.setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent);
// Notifications are issued by sending them to the
// NotificationManager system service.
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds an anonymous Notification object from the builder, and
// passes it to the NotificationManager
mNotificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

Simply add `notifyIntent.putExtra("fromNotification", true);`

Answer (score 4):

When defining intent you put in notification add there some boolean flag as extra. Then in main activity start check if intent contains that extra.